# I'm trying to use GridbagLayout to display 2 columns of JLabels inside of a ScrollPane. What part of my code is stopping the intended results?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I'm working on a program that deals with lists of jobs with a list of contractor names for each job. This part of the program will take two lists, one with an old set of contractor names and one with an updated list of names and display them next to each other. The setup for it is a `JFrame` with a `JScrollPane` inside and a `JPanel` inside the viewport. The `JPanel` uses a `GridBagLayout` to display the two lists with the old list in column 0 and the new list in column 1. When the program runs, the two lists are in the same column. I cannot tell what makes it do this.

```java
private void displayUpdateInfoFrame(ParseFullDoc updatedDoc) {

    // set up the frame
    JFrame updateInfoFrame = new JFrame() {
        {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setTitle("Update Information");
            getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setSize(1250, 600);
        }
    };
    ArrayList<Job> oldJobs = parseFullDoc.getJobList();
    ArrayList<Job> newJobs = filterUpdatedJobs(updatedDoc);

    final ArrayList<JLabel> jobLabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    final ArrayList<Status> jobLabelStatus = new ArrayList<Status>();

    GridBagConstraints infoConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    ArrayList<JLabel> newJobLabels = getInfoLabels(JOBSET.NEW, oldJobs, newJobs, jobLabels, jobLabelStatus);
    ArrayList<JLabel> oldJobLabels = getInfoLabels(JOBSET.OLD, oldJobs, newJobs, jobLabels, jobLabelStatus);

    JScrollPane infoScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    for (int oldIndex = 0; oldIndex < oldJobLabels.size(); oldIndex++) {
        infoConstraints.gridx = 0;
        infoConstraints.gridy = oldIndex;
        infoPanel.add(oldJobLabels.get(oldIndex), infoConstraints);
    }
    for (int newIndex = 0; newIndex < newJobLabels.size(); newIndex++) {
        infoConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        infoConstraints.gridx = 1;
        infoConstraints.gridy = newIndex;
        infoPanel.add(newJobLabels.get(newIndex), infoConstraints);
    }
    GridBagConstraints infoFrameConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    infoFrameConstraints.gridx = 0;
    infoFrameConstraints.gridy = 0;
    infoFrameConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; // Fill both horizontally and vertically
    infoFrameConstraints.weightx = 1.0; // Expand horizontally
    infoFrameConstraints.weighty = 1.0; // Expand vertically

    infoScrollPane.setViewportView(infoPanel);
    updateInfoFrame.add(infoScrollPane, infoFrameConstraints);
    updateInfoFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I first tried two scroll panes next to each other, but only one showed on the frame. I've tried to exclude the scroll pane, with only the `JPanel` inside the frame, but it still shows the two lists in the same column. I've tried to add a column in between the two lists, but it still doesn't show properly.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a collection of `JLabel`s, I suggest using two [JList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)s, each in its own, separate [JScrollPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and put those two `JScrollPane`s in a `JPanel` with [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).

Here is a complete example.
(Note that I simply hard-coded two lists.)

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class TwoLists {

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createLists(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JScrollPane createList(List<String> elems) {
        String[] arr = elems.toArray(new String[]{});
        JList<String> list = new JList<String>(arr);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private JPanel createLists() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        panel.add(createList(getOldList()));
        panel.add(createList(getNewList()));
        return panel;
    }

    private List<String> getNewList() {
        return List.of("new 0", "new 1", "new 2", "new 3", "new 4");
    }

    private List<String> getOldList() {
        return List.of("old 0", "old 1", "old 2", "old 3", "old 4");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new TwoLists().createAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

Here is a screen capture:

[image: screen capture]